# Pulling all data from SQLite table column using C# iteration

Tags: c#, sqlite

I've written an SQL query using stringbuilder and send it off to the database using `SqlteDataReader` as seen below:

```
string criteria = String.Format("SELECT tile_id FROM {0} WHERE zoom_level = 14", dbTable);
                    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(criteria, dbConn);
                    SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {

                        Console.WriteLine("Starting reader: \n");
                        foreach (var i in reader)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(i);
                        }
                    }
              isMet = true;
                }
            catch (Exception E )
            {
                Console.Write(E.StackTrace);
            }
```

`dbTable` == `map`. I've ran the above SQL query through an SQLite browser and it's pulled back the correct information.

The returned value is always `System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal` and after some Googling around I'm still a little lost. A lot of solutions that I've found implement a `DataReader` which solves the issue but I'm already using one.

`tile_id` is stored as `TEXT` in SQLite, and so far I've tried to retrieve it formatted as `string`, `var` and `int`, all of which have returned the above value.

Can anyone offer some advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need that `foreach` loop. You should change the reader reading code to be

```
            Console.WriteLine("Starting reader: \n");
            while (reader.Read())
            {
              Console.WriteLine(reader["tile_id"].ToString());
            }
```

See [Retrieving Data Using a DataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx). for more information.

Comment: Great, thank you so much. Always nice to find shorter solutions! Marking as correct.

Answer (score 1):

`reader.Read()` already moves to the next record if any. So Use:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting reader: \n");
    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
}
```